# web3 ethereum subscribe doesn't work all the time

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, web3js, wss

Sometimes I face this problem when subscribe method does not work. And I can't find a way to debug either the subscribe action started or not. Even "error" and "end" handlers seems not working.

```
async initWssServer(e = false) {
    if (e) {
        console.error('WSS disconnected')
        console.error(e)
    }

    this.server = await new Web3('wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws')
    this.events = events

    const subscribe = this.server.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders', async (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return this.initWssServer(err)
        }

        return this.events.emit('new_block', data)
    })

    subscribe.on('error', e => this.initWssServer(e))
    subscribe.on('end', e => this.initWssServer(e))

    return true
}
```

Is there a way to check if subscribe started and if not - replay it or do something instead?

Comment: maybe this help if you put:  await this.server.eth.subscribe

Comment: that is not helpful.